# Ajax not picking up php post from dymanically created form

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have created some ajax that uploads an image and loads it into the page.

It creates an images with an X button on the top corner, I am trying to get it so when this button is clicked I then run another peice of php code with will delete the correct image and reload the images.

I cant get my ajax code to pick up the php code and I am not sure why.

Any pointed would be very helpful.

I have found out that dymanically created elemets will not be picked up so had to change my ajax code to

```
$("body").on("click", "#deleteform button", function(e){
```

so I am hitting this point but but it sill is not picking up my php code and I dont know why.

Any pointers would be very helpful

AJAX JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#uploadForm").on('submit',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
              url: "include_advert/advert_new_gun_add_image.inc.php",
          type: "POST",
          data:  new FormData(this),
          contentType: false,
          cache: false,
          processData:false,
          success: function(data)
            {
          $("#targetLayer").html(data);
            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
          });
      });
    });




      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button.deleteimage').on('click', function(){
            var image_id = parseInt($(this).parent().attr('id').replace('deleteform', ''));

            console.log(image_id); // You can comment out this. Used for debugging.

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "include_advert/advert_new_gun_delete_image.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  {image_id: image_id},
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#targetLayer"+image_id).html(data); // targetLayer is dynamic and is different for each record
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**HTML**:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="include_advert/advert_js/advert_gun_load_save_images.js"></script>
                <div class="bgColor">
                <form id="uploadForm" action="include_advert/advert_new_gun_add_image.inc.php" method="post" class="login-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div id="targetLayer" class=col> </div>
                <div id="uploadFormLayer">
                <input name="file" type="file" class="inputFile"  /><br/>

                <div class="text-center">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD" class="btn btn-common log-btn">
                </div>
                </form>
```

**advert_new_gun_add_image.inc.php**:

```
<?php

$imagecount = 0;
            echo ('<div class=row sm>');

            foreach ($getadvertimages as $getadvertimages_row) {
                echo ( '<div class="image-area" >
                <form  id="deleteform'.$getadvertimages_row['image_id'].'" method = "POST" action ="include_advert/advert_new_gun_delete_image.php" >
                <img src="'. $getadvertimages_row['image_src'] . '"  alt="Preview">
                <button  onclick = "" name="deleteimage" id="deleteimage" value="'. $getadvertimages_row['image_id'] . '" class="remove-image" style="display: inline;" >X</button>

                </form>
                </div>');
            }
            echo ('</div>');
```

**advert_new_gun_delete_image.php**:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['deleteimage']) ){
echo('hello');
}?>
```

I am expecting when I click the button on the image it will run the advert_new_gun_delete_image.php file without reloading the complete page

Comment: convert `id="deleteform"` to `class="deleteform"` , because `id` used to address unique element while `class` used to address group of similar elements and in your case `images` are similar elelements

Comment: Try to add slash(/) in front of url or try to give full url to fire an ajax

Comment: Did you check the console for errors ? alert something on clicking button, can you see alert ?

Comment: There are no errors its just running and opening advert_new_gun_delete_image.php but I want this up run without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button.delete-button').on('click', function(){
            var image_id = parseInt($(this).parent().attr('id').replace('deleteform', ''));

            console.log(image_id); // You can comment out this. Used for debugging.

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "include_advert/advert_new_gun_delete_image.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  {image_id: image_id},
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#targetLayer"+image_id).html(data); // targetLayer is dynamic and is different for each record
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```
include 'advert_new_gun_save_image_script.inc.php';
include 'advert_new_dropdown_populate/advert_new_gun_image_populate.php';

$imagecount = 0;
echo ('<div class=row sm>');

foreach ($getadvertimages as $getadvertimages_row) {
    echo ( '<div class="image-area" >
    <form  id="deleteform'.$getadvertimages_row['image_id'].'" method = "POST" action ="include_advert/advert_new_gun_delete_image.php" >
    <img src="'. $getadvertimages_row['image_src'] . '"  alt="Preview">
    <button type="button" name="deleteimage" value="" class="remove-image delete-button" style="display: inline;" >X</button>

    </form>
    </div>');
}
echo ('</div>');
```

Similarly you can make "targetLayer" dynamic with image_id value just like I did with form's attribute id deleteform.

Comment: Hello @Ghulam  , Thanks for you reply - I made the chages like to suggested I have edited my question showing this. But my code is just going to the include_advert/advert_new_gun_delete_image.php file and opening this in the browser. This is what I am trying to avoid. and Idea why this is happening?

Comment: It is not hitting the $('button.delete-button').on('click', function(){ at all

Answer (score 0):

The Above Answer was almost there but I had to change the  `$('button.delete-button').on('click', function(){` to `$("body").on("click", "#deleteimage", function(e){`

And I also removed:`contentType: false, cache: false,processData:false,`

Thanks Ghulam for the push in the right direction

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
                $("body").on("click", "#deleteimage", function(e){
                    var image_id = parseInt($(this).parent().attr('id').replace('deleteform', ''));

                    console.log(image_id); // You can comment out this. Used for debugging.

                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "include_advert/advert_new_gun_delete_image.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data:  {image_id: image_id },

                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            $('#imageareadiv').hide();
                            $("#targetLayer").html(data); // targetLayer is dynamic and is different for each record
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).delegate('#deleteform button', 'click', function (e) {
```

instead of

```
$("body").on("click", "#deleteform button", function(e){
```

Comment: Warning:- Deprecated > Deprecated 3.0